# Having issues getting a php module to run

Tags: php, module, imagemagick, imagick

I've installed imagemagick on my server which works fine, and have installed imagick using pecl, the module appears if I type php -m, yet it doesn't appear with phpinfo() and is not available in php, is there a way to quickly debug to find out why it is there but not running, or does someone have a solution to get it working?

Comment: Just a guess - have you restarted apache?

Comment: Yes, I restart apache before I attempt to check!

Comment: It's possible that your php cli binary is from a separate distribution of php than the one being used by your Apache server.  Check to see if you have multiple versions of PHP installed.

Comment: check the phpinfo() output to see which php.ini files CLI and Apache are using just in case they're different. Have a look in the Apache error log too in case there are any clues there (incorrect permissions on the .so, etc)

Comment: There are two different php.ini files being used, i'm using virtualmin if that helps?

Comment: "There are two different php.ini files being used".  Then make sure *both* include extension=imagick.so

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all the guys above for helping, I found that looking within the results from phpinfo(); that I needed to edit the file in the 'Loaded Configuration File' which seems to be site specific within each of the website folders as opposed to the usual php.ini in the /etc folder, I placed the extension=imagick.so in the site specific php.ini, restarted apache and it worked immediately!